# Google Cloud Search API - Search Example PHP

Tags: php, api, google-cloud-platform

I discovered the new (**Google API** **Cloud Search API** : https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/reference/rest) and I would like to use the (**Suggest** : https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/reference/rest/v1/query/suggest) method. I looked all over the internet for a PHP example to use this API, but I couldn't find anything. Can you help me ?

Thank you

Julia

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) since some APIs like Cloud Search doesn't have a client library.

With APIs Client Library you can use the endpoints that are in the documentation that you [found](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/reference/rest/v1/query/suggest)

In this [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#making-http-requests-directly) is explained how to make requests to the APIs using HTTP calls.